# How do I display a LineChart control ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display a Line Chart depending of the DropDownList control.

When I choose a value of this DropDown, the Line Chart display with the average of my value column group by the value of my DropDown.

The column Entite is a Varchar type and AvancementQuantitatifT1 is a decimal (3,2) type.

Nothing display when I choose a value of my DropDownList.

This is my code behind :

```
 protected void entite_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = string.Format("select Entite, AVG(AvancementQuantitatifT1 * 100) FROM reponse WHERE Entite = '{0}' GROUP BY Entite", NomEntite.SelectedItem.Value);
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);

            string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
            }
            LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Data = y });
            LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);
            LineChart1.ChartTitle = string.Format("{0}", NomEntite.SelectedItem.Value);
            if (x.Length > 3)
            {
                LineChart1.ChartWidth = (x.Length * 75).ToString();
            }
            LineChart1.Visible = true;
        }
```

My SQL Query works fine in SQL Management studio.

EDIT

Screenshot of my dt table :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VotIt.png

Comment: Debug and see data in 'dt' table

Comment: How ? I run with F5 but how can I see data in dt table ?

Comment: Put breakpoint at line "DataTable dt=GetData(query)",press F10 and then select "dt" and see in QuickView

Comment: I edited my first post with a screenshot. i don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

First, modify/debug your query string:

```
string query = "SELECT Entite, AVG(AvancementQuantitatifT1 * 100) As AvrVal FROM reponse WHERE Entite = '" + (sender As ComboBox).Text + "' GROUP BY Entite")
```

and check if `DataTable dt` contains records (insert a breakpoint at line `string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count]`, then move cursor over `dt` and use TableVisualization option).

Note: **reponse**  - is it correct Table Name?

The rest will depend on the result of this important step (make sure that `DataTable dt` indeed contains records and is not `null`; it seems that it's null based on your screenshot), Rgds,

Comment: The problem is not a ComboBox, it's a DropDownList control called NomEntite (for me).

Comment: Well, DropDownList is just another name for ComboBox. The Logic as described in my solution is the same: get the correct SQL string (for test purpose, just hardcode some value instead of picking it from DropDownList and make sure you got a valid DataTable object that contains records). Rgds,

Comment: Ok thanks. For the LineChart, we have to put a ToolkitScriptManager in the aspx page. But for me, I don't have the ToolkitScriptManager control so I put :  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> and yes this is a table "reponse" because on Management Studio, it works.